# Archive of older versions of original Awk source code?

Tags: awk, history

I'm trying to find "historical" versions of the source code to original Awk (a/k/a One True Awk). I found [Kernighan's occasionally-updated site](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/), which always seems to link to the latest version, but I haven't yet found a cache of older versions. My mail to Kernighan (a month or so ago) has also not been answered, so I figured I'd broadcast the request to a wider audience.

Per comments on the question, among my assets are now a version dated 2005-04-24 from the [Awk Annoyances](http://www.samiam.org/awk/annoyances.html) page and four versions from the 2010–2012 date range courtesy the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/), and two versions (2004-02-07 and 2007-05-01) found by doing a web search for `awk.tar.gz`.

FWIW, my intention is to flesh out [my public git repo of One True Awk](https://github.com/danfuzz/one-true-awk) with as many versions as I can get ahold of.

---

Update 2013-04-11: I've now integrated all the versions I found into the abovementioned repo. I'd still love to find more to fill in the gaps, though.

Comment: have you tried the Wayback Archive ? as it is probable it was at some point on some site's static html page... ex: (you can alter the date in the url until you find it) : http://web.archive.org/web/20080606071720/http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/

Comment: http://www.samiam.org/awk/annoyances.html has some infos as well, making it probably very hard to find the original. Have you thought about contacting the author himself?

Comment: Using the Wayback Machine is a great idea, thanks! Per my original question, in fact I did mail Kernighan a while ago but never heard back from him.

Comment: It looks like the Wayback Machine's oldest version of `awk.tar.gz` is actually from 2010, even though it has older versions of the index HTML page.

Comment: sorry ^^ Ask the man directly! I'm sure *he* have it (or if he doesn't, he knows someone who have it. And if not, he will tell you)

Comment: Really, I mailed K and he didn't respond. Not that big a deal AFAIC. I'll edit the question to indicate what I now have. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the original (Unix version 7, 1979) source code:

http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/awk

Comment: Thanks. There's also an "addendum" release at that site, that has a slightly later version. Still need to fill in a lot of gaps between 1979 and 2010, though!